# How to access AlertDialog's Message and Title in Unity Android Plugin Library? (I am using custom Font in AlertDialog)

Tags: java, c#, android, unity-game-engine

I want to use custom font in my android plugin library while using `AlertDialog`. Now here is the code to display `AlertDialog` using custom font.

```cs
AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mainActivity).setTitle("Title").setMessage("Message Text").create();
alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEGATIVE, "Cancel", dialogOnClickListener);

TextView alertMessageTextView = (TextView) alertDialog.findViewById(R.id.message); // I am getting error here
TextView alertTitleTextView = (TextView) alertDialog.findViewById(android.R.id.title); // I am getting error here

Typeface customFont = Typeface.createFromAsset(mainActivity.getResources().getAssets(), "fonts/lobster-regular.ttf");

alertMessageTextView.setTypeface(customFont);
alertTitleTextView.setTypeface(customFont);

alertDialog.show();
```

I am getting error:

> `Error Unity AndroidJavaException: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: No static field message of type I in class Lcom/cptech/pluginexample/R$id; or its superclasses (declaration of 'com.cptech.pluginexample.R$id' appears in base.apk)`

I have placed my font file in Unity's **"Assets/Resources"** Folder. Hence in final apk the font resources appear in **"assets/fonts"** folder. But however, this doesn't matter as, I can use custom font in other `TextView`(s).

The only problem is that it cannot find AlertDialog's message and title, as I believe. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Few changes:

Use `show()` instead of `create()` when building the `AlertDialog`:

```
AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mainActivity).setTitle("Title").setMessage("Message Text").show();
```

Then, replace this line:

```
TextView messageTextView = (TextView) alertDialog.findViewById(R.id.message);
```

With `android.R.id.message` instead, like so:

```
TextView messageTextView = (TextView) alertDialog.findViewById(android.R.id.message);
```

And make sure you're not accidentally doing `import com.android.R` at the top of your file. You need this change because the id `message` is not an asset in your module, it's a default asset from an android library. So the `R` you're using right now is coming from your package - you  need to specify `R` from `android.R`.

Last thing quick, watch out for the variable name of the textview when you set the text, should be changed to `messageTextView`