# Custom font for Alert Dialog message

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, android-styles

I'm using the following style for my custom AlertDialog. The specified font "myfont.tff" is applied on the AlertDialog title and buttons, but not on the AlertDialog message. What do I need to set to make it apply to the message, too?

```
<style name="CustomAlertDialog" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert">
    <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/myfont</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/black</item>
</style>
```

Comment: You can address this topic [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50103319/18515851)

Comment: That is the correct answer, thanks @Jordy !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The preferred way (through styles) was pointed out by @Jordy: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50103319/18515851

There is also an alternative way to achieve the same, programmatically: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66712003/963022